# Использование парсера PJSIP в проекте

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pjsip

[Скачал](http://www.pjsip.org/download.htm) и собрал `PJSIP` в `Visual Studio 2013`. 
Собрал, открыв `*.sln` в главном разделе скачанной библиотеки и нажав собрать в `Release-Static`, без ошибок среды.

Потом выяснил, что собралось куча различных `*.lib` в разных папках.

Для проекта нужен, по-сути, только парсер `SIP` (`SDP` - возможно, ну и формировка ответа). Какие из этих `*.lib` и `*.h` подключать к проекту для дальнейшего использования?

**UPDATE:**

Пробовал в тестовом проекте подключить в `VC++ Directories->Include Directories` все папки `include` из всех проектов в корне библиотеки и, соответственно, в `VC++ Directories->Library Directories` все папки `lib` во всех проектах и папку `lib` в корне библиотеки.

По мануалу подключил следующие заголовки:

```
#include <pjlib.h>
#include <pjlib-util.h>
#include <pjsip.h>
#include <pjsip_ua.h>
#include <pjsip_simple.h>
#include <pjsua.h>
#include <pjmedia.h>
#include <pjmedia-codec.h>
```

А затем в `main()` вызвал `pj_init();`
На что линковщик коротко ругнулся: 
`Test_SIP.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _pj_init`

Все библиотеки подключил, а ссылка не найдена... Может, сейчас попробую еще в ручную прописать все библиотеки, но, думаю, это успеха не принесет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решала ручная линковка. Вот как выглядит файл `stdafx.h`:

```
#pragma once
#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#include <pjlib.h>
#include <pjlib-util.h>
#include <pjsip.h>
#include <pjsip_ua.h>
#include <pjsip_simple.h>
#include <pjsua.h>
#include <pjmedia.h>
#include <pjmedia-codec.h>

/*Эти библиотеки тоже нужны*/
#pragma comment (lib,"wsock32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib,"ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib,"ole32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib,"dsound.lib")


#pragma comment (lib,"libpjproject-i386-Win32-vc14-Release.lib")
#pragma comment (lib,"pjlib-i386-Win32-vc14-Release.lib")
#pragma comment (lib,"pjlib-util-i386-Win32-vc14-Release.lib")
#pragma comment (lib,"pjmedia-audiodev-i386-Win32-vc14-Release.lib")
#pragma comment (lib,"pjmedia-codec-i386-Win32-vc14-Release.lib")
#pragma comment (lib,"pjmedia-i386-Win32-vc14-Release.lib")
#pragma comment (lib,"pjmedia-videodev-i386-Win32-vc14-Release.lib")
#pragma comment (lib,"pjnath-i386-Win32-vc14-Release.lib")
#pragma comment (lib,"pjsip-core-i386-Win32-vc14-Release.lib")
#pragma comment (lib,"pjsip-simple-i386-Win32-vc14-Release.lib")
#pragma comment (lib,"pjsip-ua-i386-Win32-vc14-Release.lib")
#pragma comment (lib,"pjsua2-lib-i386-Win32-vc14-Release.lib")
#pragma comment (lib,"pjsua-lib-i386-Win32-vc14-Release.lib")
```

А также, для меньшего ... количества набираймого текста в настройках проекта, все папки `include` и `lib`  были объединены в общие папки `includeAll` и `libAll`.